# Display additional data while iterating over a Django formset

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a list of soccer matches for which I'd like to display forms. The list comes from a remote source.

```
matches = ["A vs. B", "C vs. D", "E vs, F"]
matchFormset = formset_factory(MatchForm,extra=len(matches))
formset = MatchFormset()
```

On the template side, I would like to display the formset with the according title (i.e. "A vs. B").

```
{% for form in formset.forms %}
    <fieldset>
        <legend>{{TITLE}}</legend>
        {{form.team1}} : {{form.team2}}
    </fieldset>
{% endfor %}
```

Now how do I get `TITLE` to contain the right title for the current form? Or asked in a different way: how do I iterate over `matches` with the same index as the iteration over `formset.forms`?

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that in the Django template language there is no built-in filter for indexing, but there is one for slicing (`slice`) -- and therefore I think that, in a pinch, you could use a 1-item slice (with `forloop.counter0:forloop.counter`) and `.first` on it to extract the value you want.

Of course it would be easier to do it with some cooperation from the Python side -- you could just have a context variable `forms_and_matches` set to `zip(formset.forms, matches)` in the Python code, and, in the template, `{% for form, match in forms_and_matches %}` to get at both items simply and readably (assuming Django 1.0 or better throughout this answer, of course).

Comment: Thank you so much, Alex. Zipping is such a beautiful and simple solution!

Comment: Home someone catches this... I'm hoping to use exactly the same thing, but doesn't this (extracting forms from the formset) lose the formset manager (the meta information about number of forms, initial forms, maybe more) that is included with the formset container? Then when reading POST data, it wouldn't know how many forms to load..?

Answer (score 2):

This is an addition to Alex's answer.

I did some reading after my comment on Alex's answer and found that it is important to get the management form (basically a meta-form with information about how many forms are in the formset) into your template for your submitted data to be treated as a formset rather than just a pile of forms. [Documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform).

The only two ways I know to get that into your template are:

1. Send the formset in addition to whatever data structure you made,
   and then render the management form with {{ my_formset.management_form }}
2. Render the management form in your view and send that as an item to your template

Of course if you use Alex's first method, the formset is already available so you can add the management form directly.